# How to merge overlapping vertices into a new shape?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

I have a mesh with many overlapping and crisscrossing planes. I would like to auto-remove/merge the inner verts and criss-crossing ones to make the mesh have less vertices.

Any help appreciatted.

[image]

As you can see with this many lines any amount of vertical merging would help. Linear dissolve doesn't seem to work and merge by distance will get rid of the paths in leu of 1 line of verts, if that makes sense. These are small scales I'm working with.

Comment: Can you upload an image of your mesh?

Comment: My bad dude SE said I couldn't post this? Guess it went through. Here's what I mean in the edit.